# Getting bold text in ntheorem environment containing tikz picture and minipage environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontspec, minipage, polyglossia, ntheorem

I'm getting bold text in `ntheorem` environment where I put `tikz` picture beside arabic text in `minipage` environement.

Deleting `AutoFakeBold=1.05` option from the `\setmaincommand` let me get regular text, but I no longer can get bold text and then I need to define bold text for the theorem header `\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\sffamily}` which results in the same kind of error.

ps: I didn't have this problem before upgrading to `Tex Live 2015` and I do not remember having make any change to my code.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathrsfs,stmaryrd,euscript,fourier}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%~~~                            SETTING ARABIC LANGUAGE                         ~~~
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[quiet,nolocalmarks]{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,hijricorrection=1,locale=mashriq,numerals=maghrib]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,
             Numbers=Uppercase,
             Scale=1.3, 
             AutoFakeSlant=-0.2,
             ItalicFont=AnotherArabicFont Slanted,
             AutoFakeBold=1.05
             ]{Scheherazade}
\setsansfont[Scale=1.0,
             AutoFakeSlant=-0.2,
             ItalicFont=AnotherArabicFont Slanted,
             AutoFakeBold=1.0,
             Numbers=Lowercase]{Arial}                           
\setmonofont[Scale=1.0,Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine}   

\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1.05,                     
                           AutoFakeSlant=-0.2,
                           AutoFakeBold=1.05
                          ]{Scheherazade}
%_______________________ End of Arabic languuage Settings __________________________%
  {\theoremstyle{break}
   \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
   \newtheorem{exo}{تمرين}
   }
\newcommand\bookcolor{cyan}
%::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
%:::::                                    BEGIN OF DOCUMENT                                       :::::
%::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
\begin{document}

\begin{exo}~\\
    \begin{minipage}{.54\linewidth}
        نص عربي
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.42\linewidth}
        \selectlanguage{english}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-1.5:15.5,scale=.65]\footnotesize    
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xone}{-5}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwo}{ 5}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\yone}{-4}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwo}{5}
                % grid
                \draw[step=.5 cm,\bookcolor!60,very thin] (\xone cm,\yone cm) grid (\xtwo cm,\ytwo cm);
                \draw[step=1 cm,\bookcolor!80,very thin] (\xone cm,\yone cm) grid (\xtwo cm,\ytwo cm);
                % ticks
                \foreach \x/\xtext in {-3/-3,-2/-2,-1/-1,1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
                \draw[\bookcolor,xshift=\x cm] (0,.1) -- (0,-0.1) node[below] {$\xtext$};
                \foreach \y/\ytext in {-3/-3,-2/-2,-1/-1,1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
                \draw[\bookcolor, yshift=\y cm] (.1,0) -- (-.1,0) node[left] {$\ytext$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \selectlanguage{arabic}
    \end{minipage}
\end{exo}
نص عربي
\begin{exo}~\\
    \begin{minipage}{.50\linewidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item سؤال أول 
            \item سؤال ثاني
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage} \vline\hspace{.5cm}
    \begin{minipage}{.50\linewidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item سؤال أول 
            \item سؤال ثاني
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
\end{exo}
% Second Example
\begin{minipage}{.54\linewidth}
    نص عربي
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.42\linewidth}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-1.5:15.5,scale=.65]\footnotesize    
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xone}{-5}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwo}{ 5}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yone}{-4}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwo}{5}
            % grid
            \draw[step=.5 cm,\bookcolor!60,very thin] (\xone cm,\yone cm) grid (\xtwo cm,\ytwo cm);
            \draw[step=1 cm,\bookcolor!80,very thin] (\xone cm,\yone cm) grid (\xtwo cm,\ytwo cm);
            % ticks
            \foreach \x/\xtext in {-3/-3,-2/-2,-1/-1,1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
            \draw[\bookcolor,xshift=\x cm] (0,.1) -- (0,-0.1) node[below] {$\xtext$};
            \foreach \y/\ytext in {-3/-3,-2/-2,-1/-1,1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
            \draw[\bookcolor, yshift=\y cm] (.1,0) -- (-.1,0) node[left] {$\ytext$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \selectlanguage{arabic}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that this example should be called "MWE". It is certainly not minimal.

Comment: I put only the necessary code with three different cases of application of minipage environment 
1- with tikz picture 
2- with enumerate environment
3- out of ntheorem environment

Comment: A minimal example would contain just enough to demonstrate the problem. Does dropping `url` or `chngcntr` or `setspace` solve the problem? Does it work with minimal picture content? If so, can you do without one of the packages or figure out the problem in the picture code? If not, why are they part of your example?

Comment: Note that I don't really know, to be honest, what is supposed to be different about the output. Should none of the script shown be bold? What is the purpose of the three cases exactly? It is rather confusing - at least for somebody to whom the content means nothing at all. (Obviously this is my ignorance but you probably want help from the ignorant here, since the number of potential helpers is otherwise likely to be rather small and it may take a long time for one of them to show up.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you have any idea what's going on in the more minimal case I posted below? According to the OP, this problem is new with an update from 2013 to 2015.  Should `bidi` be used here? The mix of RTL and LTR typesetting makes me think it should, but I am on shaky ground....

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much more minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[nolocalmarks]{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Noto Kufi Arabic}[%
  Script=Arabic,
  AutoFakeBold=1.05]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}

\theorembodyfont{\normalfont\upshape}
\newtheorem{exo}{تمرين}

\begin{document}
\begin{exo}~\\
  \begin{minipage}{.54\linewidth}
    نص عربي
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.42\linewidth}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {ABC};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
\end{exo}
\end{document}
```

[image: more minimal]

This may not be truly minimal as I did not finish eliminating everything which I might have tried to eliminate. But it is certainly closer to being usably minimal than the original example.

Note that adding a single letter before the `tikzpicture` prevents the theorem body showing in bold.

So I think that the basic problem here is trying to mix LTR and RTL typesetting on a single link.

For example, if you use

```
\begin{exo}~\\
  \selectlanguage{english}%
  \begin{minipage}{.42\linewidth}%
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node {ABC};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
  \selectlanguage{arabic}
  \begin{minipage}{.54\linewidth}
    نص عربي
  \end{minipage}
\end{exo}
```

then the fonts come out correctly (although things are in the wrong places, obviously).

You probably need to look at `bidi` to think about managing a mix of RTL and LTR typesetting in a single document properly.

However, I'm not sure if mixing them on a single line is possible, even so. (But I am far from knowledgeable about this - I just couldn't see anything looking quickly.)

Comment: For the example that you gave above, as you said things are not in the right places, on the other hand I opted for a long time the use of the polyglossia package since it have less conflict problems with the right to left scripts and I found it more comfortable in use.
But I'm wondering here if the problem always arises with version of Tikz prior to version 3.

Comment: Why do you think it is version related? I'm certainly using version 3.

Comment: I encountered this problem only after upgrading to `TeX Live 2015`, before this I was using `TeX Live 2013` and things was working good for me. my prior `Tikz` version was the 2.1v.
After this upgrade I have had to change from `Linux Libertine` font for the english laguage as I've had dotted lines exceeding the margin and I was also getting the same problem with enumerated lists in minipage environment which I do correct by adding `AutoFakeBold` option to the english font.

Comment: So maybe you meant that the problem might arise for TikZ version 3 and not for versions prior to 3? I'd be more inclined to suspect changes to XeTeX, to be honest. But I certainly don't know - that's just a guess.

Comment: Exact, that's what I meant.